# Load electron modules in Angular 2 and Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, electron

I'm using [this starter kit](https://github.com/cmelo/angular2-electron-starter) to create an electron application. When i try to import electron modules into an Angular 2 component like this:

```
const electron = require('electron');
```

I get this error `fs.readFileSync is not a function` from this file in the starter kit:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = path.join(__dirname, fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt'), 'utf-8'))
```

when i do not use `require` in the component, everything works fine. It's like using `require` changes the type of `require` used elsewhere but i really don't know what's happening. I've tried other ways of importing electron modules into the angular component but i get:

```
Cannot find module 'electron'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Electron requires NodeJS the browser can't access the filesystem only the server can.

But Electron renders the index.html file using node so using the following will work with your Angular app.

In your index.html file for Angular you should place

```
  <script>
    window.electron = require("electron");
  </script>
```

An example using other parts of Electron in your Angular app.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular App</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>


  <script>
    window.electron = require("electron");
    window.ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
    window.electronRemote = require("electron").remote;
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```